# In WordPress page editor, how can one add HTML to place data pulled by shortcode in 2 columns?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend

In WordPress page editor or in the template file, how can one add HTML to put data pulled by shortcode of sheetdb in 2 columns? Below is the code that I added in a custom field, but it displays the data one below the other. Please let me know how to make it appear in 2 columns. The sheetdb plugin helps pull data from a googlesheet.

```
[sheetdb url="https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/ymk583vab4dwh" search="Approval=1&amp;Display=1"]
<div class="contest-entry-row">
<div class="story">{{Story}}</div>
<div class="contestent-name">-{{First Name}} {{Initial}}</div>
</div>
[/sheetdb]
```

Code in the PHP template file below.

//Get custom field data.

```
$story = get_field('story');

<div class="contest-story">
  <div class="wrap-x">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="contest-story-text col col-xs-12"><?php echo do_shortcode($story); ?></div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be more like a CSS issue, can you share a live demo to check?

Answer (score 0):

Try thi:

```
.contest-story-text > div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```